# Initializing Python dictionary with special pair keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

I am making a hangman game in Python, and I figured a good way to keep track of the current word would be a dictionary. Each letter would be captured by a key, with boolean values representing whether or not the player has guessed the letter.

For simplicity, I'll assume the only allowed input is guesses (i.e., even if a player knows the word right away, he or she must finish [correctly] filling in the blanks). Thus, with each guess (provided the man hasn't been hung yet), I'd check whether the dictionary values are all True, in which case the player wins.

Two questions:

1. Does the above representation sound reasonable?
2. If so, there's the issue of generating the keys in order to account for repeated letters. I thought of using tuples; for example, here is the initial representation of the word "programming"

```
('p', 0) : False

('r', 0) : False

('o', 0) : False

('g', 0) : False

('r', 1) : False

('a', 0) : False

('m', 0) : False

('m', 1) : False

('i', 0) : False

('n', 0) : False

('g', 1) : False
```

The second item in the pair is just an index for the occurrence of that letter; thus, the first item can still be used to mark correctly-guessed letters as I iterate through the word.

Given a word as a string, is there a compact way to create a dictionary as above? I can see something like this:

```
word = "programming"
word_dict = { (letter, ???) : False for letter in word }
```

, where ??? is some clever counting expression. Or do I need to do it explicitly and keep track of things in a loop?

Comment: It doesn't matter if a letter is repeated or not; the player has either guessed the letter or they haven't. Repetitions don't come into this.

Comment: *slaps self* Oh. Might it still be useful to have a structure like that for displaying progress, though? (e.g., '_ A _ _ A L _' is printed to the console after a turn?)

Comment: Not really; see my answer below; you only need to loop over the word-to-be-guessed and check against the dictionary to see if the letter has been guessed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your problem; all you really need is a dictionary with `True` and `False`; it doesn't matter if a letter is repeated or not as once the player has guessed the letter they guessed all repeats of that letter.

Creating the dictionary is then simple:

```
word_dict = dict.fromkeys(word, False)
```

This creates a dictionary with one key per *unique* letter, each defaulting to `False`.

Playing hangman is then as easy as:

```
guessed = set()
misses = 0

while misses < 6:
    if guess in guessed:
        # already guessed at this before
        # error message, user must try again
        continue

    guessed.add(guess)
    if guess not in word_dict:
        # wrong guess
        # hang the user some more
        misses += 1
    else:
        word_dict[guess] = True
        display = ''.join([c if word_dict[c] else '_' for c in word])
        print 'Guessed so far: {}'.format(display)
        if all(word_dict.values()):
            # guessed the whole word!
            # show congratulations
            break
else:
    # player died, show commiserations
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> word = 'programming'
>>> c = Counter(word)
Counter({'g': 2, 'm': 2, 'r': 2, 'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1})
```

You could use this to do something like

```
dead = 5    # maximum number of incorrect guesses
missed = 0  # current number of incorrect guesses
while missed < dead:
    guess = raw_input("guess a letter")
    if c.get(guess):
        # they guessed a correct letter, display something nice :)
        # more importantly, keep track of how much of the word they correctly know
    else:
        missed += 1
        print guess, "not a letter in the word"
```